# React Native - axios return Network Error first time

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, axios

I'm trying to upload image in react-native with axios using Laravel as backend. But axios gives Network Error for first time and second time it works perfectly.

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('profilePic', {
            uri: pic.uri,
            name: pic.uri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''),
            type: pic.type + "/" + pic.uri.split(/[#?]/)[0].split('.').pop().trim()
        });
        formData.append('userId', userId);
        await axios.post(api + 'updateDocument', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            onUploadProgress: e => {
                setProgress((e.loaded / e.total).toFixed(2))
            },
        })
```

I don't know what is problem. Why it successfully uploads second time?

Comment: why there is an await in front of your axios call ? what it is waiting for ?

Comment: @ShoyebMemon This is inside an async function, so await hold JavaScript for executing until axios promise got resolved or rejected.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I can guess you're not properly utilising useState in a functional component. therefore the updated states don't take effect the first time they are being set. they will lead to the result you desire only after the first re-render (AKA your second attempt).